# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting multiple criteria excluding first date occurrence

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, conditional-formatting, countif, find-occurrences

I have a bunch of assessment data for pre and post testing and am trying to highlight the rows in which a post-test(s) had 0 or negative gains. There is scaled gains data for the first test that I cannot remove (based on prior SY tests) and I would like to  exclude the first test for the school year. I have tried the following two formulas for conditional formatting:

=(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($R$3:$R&$U$3:$U),$R3&$U3)>1)*COUNTIFS($U3, "*Reading*", $V3, NOT(MIN($V3)), $Z3,"<=0")

- Nothing highlights

=(COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($R$3:$R&$U$3:$U),$R3&$U3)>1)*COUNTIFS($U3, "*Reading*", $V3, MAX($V3), $Z3,"<=0")

- Negative gains, including the first test date highlight

The (COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA($R$3:$R&$U$3:$U),$R3&$U3)>1) portion checks the student id and test to highlight only those that have tested more than once and based on the research I did, the second portion *COUNTIFS($U3, "*Reading*", $V3, MAX($V3), $Z3,"<=0") should act as additional criteria looking for the specific subject area (col U), test date (col V) and scaled gains (col Z)

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a simplified version of the data (actual sheet has a lot more data related to the specific tests and students that is not relative to the formula): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NtD9JaIAqq0Lz-6LAvxSAXeo-WpwZtszped6Ou4iwzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Here is a simplified version of the data I am working with for this formula and an example of which data I want the formula to highlight https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NtD9JaIAqq0Lz-6LAvxSAXeo-WpwZtszped6Ou4iwzo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally need array formulas for conditional formatting. You just need to get it right for the top left hand corner of the range and the rest will follow as if you had pulled the formula down and across:

```
=(countifs($A$3:$A3,$A3,$B$3:$B3,$B3)>1)*($E3<=0)
```

[image]

*Note*

I've assumed that the scores are in date order within each Id and test, but the formula can be adjusted if not